# Preferred way to use favicons?

Tags: browser, compatibility

I was trying to add a favicon to a website earlier and looked for a better way to implement this than to dump a `favicon.ico` file in the root of the website.

I found this nice little guide: [How to Add a Favicon](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon). However, the preferred method did not work in IE (7) and the second method is the old fashioned way (which I resigned myself to use).

Is there a third method that works across all the most popular browsers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what I always use:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />  
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

The second one is for IE. The first one is for other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML to specify the favicon, but that will only work on pages that have this HTML.  A better way to do this is by adding the following to your httpd.conf (Apache):

```
AddType image/x-icon .ico
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most reliable method is the simply added the **favicon.ico** file to the root of your website.

I don't think there is any need for a meta tag unless you want to manually override the default favicon, but I was unable to find any research to support my argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is how they're doing it right here on Stack Overflow:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the file is in the root so it does not show whether the tag works or if the browser just got the icon from the usual location (the root).

**Edit:** I'll try it and see if it works.

**Edit 2:** Using both tags make it work even for any file name as long as the file is an icon for IE7: I tried using **`.png`** files and it only worked with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million different ways these icons are used (different browsers, different platforms, mobile site-pinning, smart TVs, etc, etc), so there's really no longer a simple answer. For a great explanation see [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969053/7343159), but the short answer is:

Use this site which lets you upload a png/jpg and then does all the hard work for you: https://realfavicongenerator.net/