# Why doesn't my favicon display for my web site?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, favicon

I have a website that I've just uploaded onto the Internet.  When I browse to the site using Firefox 3.0.1 on Ubuntu I don't see the favicon; Firefox 3.0.1 on WinXP does display it.

**Why** isn't the favicon displaying under Ubuntu?   It's a favicon.ico file in the root directory, not referenced in the meta tags; would it work better as a GIF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Previously, there was no favicon.  The browser cached the lack of favicon.  [Clear the Firefox cache](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/maintenance/ht/clearcacheff.htm), and all is well.

Answer (score 5):

Try taking a look at this [previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642/perfect-way-to-use-favicons), which shows you must put two meta tags in your html in order for it to work across all browsers and operating systems.