# Image icon beside the site URL

Tags: web-applications, favicon

I would like to have information about the icons which are displayed alongside the site URLs on a web browser. Is this some browser specific feature? Where do we specify the icon source, ie, is it in some tag on the web page itself ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that

Answer (score 51, accepted):

These icons are called [favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

Most web browsers support http://mysite.com/favicon.ico but the proper way to do it is to include an icon meta tag in the head profile.

```
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="/somewhere/myicon.png" />
[…]
</head>
```

[Source from the W3C itself.](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

Your best bet is to probably do both with the same icon image.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you're referring to the [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), which allows a website to specify a 16x16 (or larger) image which is displayed in the address bar next to the URL in most modern browsers.

Some browsers just pick the file called favicon.ico which is in the root of your web folder, whereas others require it to be specified in the `<head>` of the HTML using the following code,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This was originally the way it was done with IE, but that doesn't conform to standards (because of the space in the rel), so most browsers now let you do it as follows, where you can use any standard image format, not just .ico

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called a favicon.

You might want to check out these three questions:

- [What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that support Favicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that)
- [Why no favicon for my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732/why-no-favicon-for-my-web-site)
- [Preferred way to use favicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642/preferred-way-to-use-favicons)

Answer (score 0):

These are [favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) - more info on that page.

Basically, .ico files in the root directory on the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I will just add that some sites use an animated Gif as favicon. Which can be seen as über cool or supremely annoying, depending on your tastes... And probably not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get that info is by this simple web app

[link text](http://www.getfavicon.org)

You only have to type the url of the page and it returns all the image properties

Answer (score 0):

They're [favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). Browsers look at / on a server for favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

This is called favicon you can look on this tutorial using favicon in asp.net application [LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/add-a-favicon-to-your-Asp-Net-page/)

Answer (score -3):

It was originally a windows icon format file, stored under the URL http://site/favicon.ico.  Most sites still use favicon.ico, and many browsers still automatically look there, regardless of the meta tags.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Windows.

Comment: Of course it does, the original favicon was implemented by Microsoft.  The only backwards compatible format is the windows .ico format.
Not only that, but some browsers ignore the meta tags and load the url anyways..

Comment: It was originally an Internet Explorer feature, with the Windows icon format as the only supported format.