# How to display text in browsers tab bar in a javaserver page

Tags: html, jsp, browser, text, tabs

I have heard of being able to display images in a browsers tab bar here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120420/image-icon-beside-the-site-url
```

But I was wondering if there might be an easier way to do this for just some simple text? I am trying to display just two lines, last login and IP address in this location.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser tabs display the FavIcon and the `<title>` of the page. You can't really display multiple lines in a browser tab, though you could separate information you want to display in it with a `-`, which is pretty common practice.

For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title - Awesome Web Page</title>
        <link rel="icon" 
              type="image/png" 
              href="/somewhere/myicon.png" />

...
```

Sets the tab to display the text `My Title - Awesome Web Page` and to have the image `myicon.png` as the icon on the tab.

Any more complex information should be in the actual body of your document.