# Personalized icon next to the URL address in the browser's address bar?

Tags: html

How do I write code where a company icon appears on the left side next to the URL address in the browser's address bar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for a [Favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642/preferred-way-to-use-favicons#6645).

Answer (score 4):

it loads www.whateveryouron.com/favicon.ico

if your domain is robermyers.com, just put a favicon.ico 16px icon thats accessible, and you're in like flint.
just try this [googles](http://www.google.com/favicon.ico) or [stackoverflows](https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a favicon. The favicon uses a standard (in Windows, at least) .ico file. If you have a logo, you can convert it at sites like http://www.favicongenerator.com/

In the `<head>` of your html page, use the `<link>` tag to define the location of the favicon like this:

```
<link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

You may need to refresh the page for the icon to display.

Answer (score 0):

load a file on the webserver called [favicon.ico](https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico)

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers other fileformats than .ico works aswell. You can even put animated gif's in there!

Answer (score 0):

[DynamicDrive has an easy favicon maker too](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/).

Different pages/directories can also call a different .ico with code similar to y0mbo's example (this is what Mint uses):

```
<link href="sc/ph645.43/images/icons/mint.ico" rel="icon" type="text/x-icon" />
```

[This](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/10/17/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-favicons/) is a good article on favicons in detail.

I suspect animated favicons have the potential to go the way of the blink tag. [Mint](https://wwws.mint.com/login.event) is using theirs to match their overall design, if you visit in FF3, you'll see that it matches the green color that FF uses to designate a recognized SSL cert.