# How can I add a picture in address bar of the browser when my page is browsed?

Tags: html, favicon

#### Duplicate:

> [Image icon beside the site URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120420/image-icon-beside-the-site-url)
>
> [What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that support Favicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that-s)
>
> [Preferred way to use favicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642/preferred-way-to-use-favicons)

I want to add my logo in the address bar of the browser, whenever it is browsed.

How do I make a favicon?

Comment: Edited title now reads like the OP already knows what a favicon is before asking about it

Comment: I agree, doesn't help people searching. If he knew it was a favicon he might have found one of the other answers. Will edit...

Comment: Interesting. I agree with both sides on this edit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) - this is a 16x16 image in [.ico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(icon_image_file_format)) format stored as favicon.ico in the root directory your site. Some browsers do support other formats too.

A newer, more standards based approach is to include something like this in your html head:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/image.png"/>
```

See also this document from W3C: [How to Add a Favicon to your Site](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

You might also want to refer to these other answers to the question:

- [Image icon beside the site URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120420/image-icon-beside-the-site-url)
- [What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that support Favicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that-s)
- [Preferred way to use favicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642/preferred-way-to-use-favicons)

Answer (score 1):

That image is called a favicon and here are some links on how to add one or you can just google "how to add a favicon" for more information.

http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

http://www.clickfire.com/favicon-tutorial

http://essentialkeystrokes.com/tutorial-how-to-create-your-own-favicon

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about creating a [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)?

If so, [here's a site](http://www.favicon.co.uk/) which will help you make one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/image.png"/>
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626377/771431)