# If I combined multiple .PNG files to make a favicon.ico file what is the proper code for it?

Tags: php, html, favicon

I combined with imagemagick 5 .png files to make one favicon.ico file, the sizes were 16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 96x96, 144x144.

Is it okay to use this code

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

or

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64 96x96 144x144" href="/favicon.ico">
```

or

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" sizes="32x32" sizes="64x64" sizes="96x96" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon.ico">
```

I have tried them all but I am not sure which is the correct/proper one

Comment: try it your self and check what was the outcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple favicon sizes, How, Where and when to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740611/multiple-favicon-sizes-how-where-and-when-to-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

Favicons are different for different browsers and devices.
So you should be able to specify the favicons sizes using the following HTML individially:

```
<link rel=icon href=favicon.png sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
 
<link rel=icon href=windows.ico sizes="32x32 48x48" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
 
<link rel=icon href=mac.icns sizes="128x128 512x512 8192x8192 32768x32768">
 
<link rel=icon href=iphone.png sizes="57x57" type="image/png">
 
<link rel=icon href=gnome.svg sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use this:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
```

However, you probably lack PNG icons. `favicon.ico` is an old artifact, originally introduced by Internet Explorer. It has been replaced long ago with PNG icons. While `favicon.ico` is still useful, you should not rely on it to implement the favicon of a modern website.

I suggest you to:

- Not embed 5 images, as they make the final file unnecessary large. Rather follow [Microsoft recommandations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/gg491740(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with just 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48.
- Add two 16x16 and 32x32 PNG icons with

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"/>
```

Even with these icons, you still lack a few icons to fully support all platforms, such as iOS. You can generate them all, along with HTML code, with [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) (I'm the author of this service).