# Ubuntu 14 Apache server, page loading icon doesn't disappear

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp

I'm new to the LAMP stack. I set up everything correctly, everything works fine, I can view a sample PHP file, but one thing that irritates me is that page loading icon. It is still active like the page was still loading, but the whole content of the page has already been loaded. I do not know how to fix this problem. I tried to ask Google but found nothing, tried to restart apache server but the problem is not solved. I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu  Is it a bug or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preferred way to use favicons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642/preferred-way-to-use-favicons)

Comment: It's not about the icon on the page. It's about the gif icon on the tab  itself, so it can't be a duplicate of the post you pasted.

Comment: That "gif icon" is called "favicon", and that is how it is loaded. /edit: if I am misunderstanding it please try to describe it better in the question.